# How to tell what tables 'interact' with other tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just was brought into a database that's a little hard to understand.  I was trying to insert a record into a table but got an error 'Cannot modify a column which maps a non-key preserved table'.  I assume I can't add a record into this table because one of the columns is sharing the same with another tables column, problem is these tables don't have a PK so I'm having a hard time trying to weed through the hundreds of tables to find out which ones exactly are interacting with this table.

Is this a query or a tool in Oracle SQL developer(1.5.5) that will show me tables interacting with this one table?

Comment: The error you're receiving appears to indicate that you are trying to insert a row into a view, not a table.  And that view does not appear to allow insert operations.  It is probably possible to modify the view to allow insert operations.  You can also insert data into the actual tables.  It's not clear, though, which of these two options you would want.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave, Is there a way to find out which view was created from which table?

Comment: You can certainly look at the query that the view is executing.  In SQL Developer, you should be able to navigate to the view and see the code (1.5.5 is an ancient version, 4.0.2 is the current version, so I'm not 100% certain about the old interface).  You can also query `dba_views` to see the `text` of the view.